# How to convert MongoDBList to BasicDBList?

Tags: scala, casbah

I use Casbah 2.5.0. There is example in tutorial:

```
scala> val builder = MongoDBList.newBuilder
scala> builder += "foo"
scala> builder += "bar"
scala> builder += "x"
scala> builder += "y"
builder.type = com.mongodb.casbah.commons.MongoDBListBuilder@...

scala> val newLst = builder.result
newLst: com.mongodb.BasicDBList = [ "foo" , "bar" , "x" , "y"]
```

So newLst here is BasicDBList.

But when I try it myself, it works different.

```
scala> val builder = MongoDBList.newBuilder
scala> builder += "foo"
scala> builder += "bar"
scala> val newLst = builder.result
newLst: com.mongodb.casbah.commons.MongoDBList = [ "foo" , "bar"]
```

newLst here is of type MongoDBList.

Why is so? How can I convert MongoDBList to BasicDBList?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an implicit conversion from `com.mongodb.casbah.commons.MongoDBList` to `com.mongodb.BasicDBList` in casbah (check `com.mongodb.casbah.commons.Implicits`):

```
implicit def unwrapDBList(in: MongoDBList): BasicDBList = in.underlying
```

Just pass MongoDBList to position where BasicDBList is expected:

```
scala>  val l: BasicDBList = newLst
l: com.mongodb.casbah.Imports.BasicDBList = [ "foo" , "bar"]
```

If you want to create `MongoDBList` from `List`:

```
scala>  val list = List("foo", "bar")
list: List[java.lang.String] = List(foo, bar)

scala>  val dbList = MongoDBList(list:_*)
dbList: com.mongodb.casbah.commons.MongoDBList = [ "foo" , "bar"]
```

Comment: Thank you. And one more question. Is there a simple way to convert List to MongoDBList(or BasicDBList)?

Comment: @SergeyPassichenko can you, please, answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15188605/scala-casbah-how-to-convert-list-to-mongodblist as well?