# Scala, Casbah - How to convert List to MongoDBList?

Tags: scala, casbah

Is there an easy way to turn List into MongoDBList(or BasicDBList) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
scala>  val list = List("foo", "bar")
list: List[java.lang.String] = List(foo, bar)

scala>  val dbList = MongoDBList(list:_*)
dbList: com.mongodb.casbah.commons.MongoDBList = [ "foo" , "bar"]
```

Hint: always read source code at first. It can provide many answers to your questions and will be useful BTW. It may be hard at first time, but then it became more and more natural.

Comment: I admire your hint on reading source. But... we've got StackOverflow. Saves my each day. :)